# 2 http servers for 2 services crashing in Node.js Bluemix app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to start 2 http servers with express in Node.js to listen to the requests of 2 Bluemix service. Both are working separately but not together. During deploying the app is being started several times without success. The meaningful part of the log is shown on the image attached.

Thanks for any advise, help!

```html
<script src="//pastebin.com/embed_js/YghQ7eFC"></script>
```

[Image about the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PdtD.png)

Comment: what's the error output?

Comment: Could you modify `http.createServer(appQA).listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3001);` to `http.createServer(appQA).listen( 3001);` ? Maybe the two servers listen the same port.

Comment: I've already tried that, and it wasn't working. But I think too that the problem could be around the ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate the previous responses which explain correctly what is happening (two servers binding on the same port), I have to add that even though locally you can have two instances binding on two different custom ports, on Bluemix you cannot have 2 instances running on the same runtime, or even a single instance listening on different ports, because the traffic is routed only on http port 80 (and https 443)
To do this:
- have a container running this two node instances
- have two runtimes

Answer (score 0):

The error log shows that the assigned port is currently in use.

Most likely the issues lies in the following code:

`...
http.createServer(appDialog).listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
...
http.createServer(appQA).listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3001);`

both will use the port `process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT` if it is assigned and if so it will cause the error.

Either create a new `ENV` value or hard fix the ports to different values.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that and tried to fix the two ports to 3000 and 3001, but the behaviour was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to get a workaround for the problem by using only 1 server for both services. It is working now, although not with a fix for 2 http servers working paralelly. I'm not a particular Node.js guru, I don't say this is the only solution for it.

Anyway thanks for the tips!

Comment: You can't have 2 HTTP ports open for a single cloud foundry application at this time. Please see [1] [2]  .                                                                                   [1] https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#ports                                                                                         [2] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073627/cloudfoundry-application-opening-two-ports

Comment: Exactly, thank you, now I know the reason of the issue!