# Spring boot 2 enabling a non-secure /health endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot 2 project with client and server authentication, and I'm trying to expose only the `/actuator/health` endpoint so it won't need any authentication.

My initial `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
    private void configureWithSsl(@NotNull HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("configuring access with ssl");
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().x509()
                .and().userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
...
}
```

and `application.yaml`

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: 'paht/to/kestore/keystore.jks'
    key-store-password: 123456
    key-store-type: JKS
    client-auth: need
    trust-store: 'paht/to/truststore/truststore.jks'
    trust-store-type: JKS
    trust-store-password: 123456
    protocol: TLS
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
```

I've tried:
1. Configuring 'channel' as insecure for the endpoint

```
    private void configureWithSsl(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .requiresChannel().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health")).requiresInsecure()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().x509()
                .and().userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
```

1. add matchers to the endpoint:

```
    private void configureWithSsl(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().x509()
                .and().userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
```

1. Add ignore to the endpoint:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health"));
}
```

I've tried all these combinations, and still I get

```
curl -k  https://localhost:8443/actuator/health
curl: (35) error:1401E412:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:sslv3 alert bad certificate
```

```
curl http://localhost:8443/actuator/health
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

I want just the health endpoint to be not secured, the rest of the actuator endpoints I do need secured, so configuring `management.server.ssl.enabled=false` won't solve the problem...

**EDIT:**

As per @Aritra Paul answer, I've also tried:

```
http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers( "/actuator/health/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers( "/**").authenticated()
        .and().x509()
        .and().userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
```

But I still get the same result.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're meaning "non-SSL" or "no Spring Security".

Comment: I've trying that the all the endpoints will be via https:// and authenticated, and the /actuator/health endpoint to not need any authentication. I've tried to clear this in the original question as well.

Comment: You seem to be missing the difference between certificate errors and application authentication errors.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? My knowledge here is indeed limited, would be happy to learn.

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate

Comment: did u manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: Is there a solution to this? Maybe some kind of filter based on Spring Security?

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar case where we added `X.509` authentication to our endpoints but wanted to keep the Spring actuator endpoints authentication-free.

With Spring 2.2.3 it is possible to configure your `server` with ssl as you have done, but disable ssl in your `management` config (which is used to configure the actuator endpoints) like this:

```
management:
  server:
    port: 8080
    ssl:
      enabled: false
```

This simple combination allowed us to hit the actuator endpoints with no auth on port 8080, while we hit the other endpoints with ssl on port 8443.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows

In `SecurityConfig` that implements `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.regexMatcher("^(?!(/actuator/)).*$")
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .x509()
            .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
```

and in `application.yaml`

```
management:
  server:
    port: 8088
    ssl:
      enabled: false
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
  health:
    livenessState:
      enabled: true
    readinessState:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score -1):

What I understand that you want to make `actuator/health` url open for all and all other url is based on role or authorization. If so You can try like bellow

```
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/actuator/health/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/other-url/**").hasRole("your role")
                .authenticated();
    }
```

Comment: I've edited my question to include what you wrote, with some differences: I need `x509` as well (both client and server certificates), and I'm unsure what is `@EnableResourceServer`, it seems I don't have the dependency needed for that annotation imported. Do I need that annotation instead of `@EnableWebSecurity`?

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and  `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` both are different things. You just replace ` configureWithSsl` . I have updated my answer

Comment: that's what I did, with addition to the `x509()` section that I must have there

Comment: but `antMatchers( "/actuator/health/**").permitAll()` and
       ` antMatchers( "/**").authenticated()` are contradictory

Comment: then how can you implement "ALL endpoints need authentication, except `actuator/health`? `.antMatchers("/other-url/**")` leaves potentially other endpoints not secured.

Comment: add your basic starter endpoint url like `antMatchers("/admin/**")`

Comment: It still won't solve the rest of the actuator endpoints, e.g. `/actuator/info` etc... That I want them to be secured

Comment: try `.anyRequest()` then

Comment: tried `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/actuator/health/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`, same result

Comment: I am not seeing any other problem here. Just crosscheck your maven dependency

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm not changing its version, it's taken from the starter